# How do I use orderby() using a Foreign Key the easiest way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

It’d like to sort a collection and use its foreign key for it. I have a 1:0...1 relationship and display it in my MVC App.

OutreachSet ==> 0:0…1 ==> MotivationSet

```
    public class OutreachSet
        {
            [Key]
            [Display(Name = "Target Contact")]
            public string TargetContact { get; set; }
            public virtual MotivationSet MotivationSet { get; set; }
         }


public class MotivationSet
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("OutreachSet")]
        [Display(Name = "Target Contact")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

 [Required]
        public virtual OutreachSet OutreachSet { get; set; }
  }

var motivations = db.Motivations.Include(m => m.OutreachSet);
var result = motivations.Select(s => s.OutreachSet).OrderByDescending(s => s.TargetContact);
```

Right here I get the content of OutreachSet but just not the TargetContact  that I want to use as an oderby criteria. Is it the best way to do it with context.Entry

The next problem that I have is that when looking at Quickwatch OutreachSet and MotivationSet semm to keep on referencing themselves infinitely.

If I use e.g. this:

```
var test = db.Entry(db.Motivations.First()).Entity.OutreachSet.TargetContact;
```

then I can't figure out how to sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve, so assuming you want to get a collection of `OutreachSet` sorted by the related `MotivationSet` `TargetContract`.

There are several ways to do that, but the simplest in your case is just to exchange the `select` and `order by` clauses in your query:

```
var result = motivations.OrderByDescending(s => s.TargetContact).Select(s => s.OutreachSet);
```